# values added to collection are duplicated multiple times over

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection of control.names that I want to populate in a msgbox to alert a user when a certain control is blank.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim icontrol As Control
    Dim colBlankFields As New Collection
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
        For Each icontrol In Me.Controls
            If icontrol.Visible = True Then
                Select Case True
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "Multi*"
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "lbl*"
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "txt*"
                        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                            colBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
                        End If
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "opt*"
                        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                            colBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
                        End If
                    Case icontrol.Name Like "cmb*"
                        If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                            colBlankFields.Add icontrol.Name
                        End If
                End Select
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    If IsEmpty(colBlankFields) Then
    Else
        MsgBox colBlankFields
    End If
End Sub
```

I left 4 fields blank and this is the col list I get (it keeps repeating)

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Do you expect those first 3 `Case` lines to be or'd together?  Execution doesn't "fall through" in VBA, so the first two `Case` checks won't do antything.

Comment: I want them to skip over if the current control in the loop does not line up with the control name in the like operator if that makes sense

Comment: OK but in that case you don't need those two lines  - anything not included is by default not checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each icontrol In Me.Controls
```

loops over every control on the whole *form*, so if you have this as an inner loop it will loop every control times the number of pages you have.

```
 For Each icontrol In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls
```

might be what you want for the inner loop so you just loop the controls on each page.

Comment: so it runs through, and I made sure to only leave one blank value on the last page (i=6) and I get a invalid call/procedure error on this line `For Each icontrol In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls` which is the last page

Comment: `For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count` - here `Count` will be one more than the index of the last page (since it's zero-based) so you need to use `Count - 1`